# Can I replace "man" with another word in words like swordman, manpower, policeman, etc?

Tags: word-usage

Do you know what are `elves` and `dwarfs`? They are fictional species for fantasy stories.

I was wondering if words like swordman, manpower, policeman, spearman, etc (everything with *man*) could be replaced with swordelf, dwarfpower, policedwarf, spearelf, etc **Can I replace the part "man" with another?**

In case of yes, about elves, would be ...elf or ...elve?

Comment: You could just use the original words.  "Tanis Half-Elven was a master swordsman" makes perfect sense.  And presumably male elves and dwarves just think of themselves as "men", the generic term for a person in those words.  (You should decide the name for our species in a story, is it Men like in Tolkein, or Humans, or...) Also what about creatures like dragons?  Is dragonpower a required quantity of dragons, or more analogous to horsepower?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but in my opinion they don't really "work," except for a few cases. The most common substitution you'll see is changing *mankind* into whatever other species. I don't think I've seen variations of *manpower* or *swordsman*. I think fantasy authors just use different words, like using *warrior* instead of *swordsman*.

Comment: I agree, and would note that we continue to use "horsepower" when referring to engines, even though the power is no longer provided by horses.

Comment: +1 Tolkien uses "gentlehobbit"; but that's by way of nudging the basic joke that the hobbits are quintessentially English.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "swordswoman" is well-attested, but that's not quite the question.

Comment: *Swordsman* would become *sword fighter* and *manpower* would become *human labour* (or just *labour* if you want to be species agnostic).

Comment: @StoneyB Good example! I was trying to remember how Tolkien handled this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You would be coining a term, albeit in a perfectly logical way. Everyone would know what you meant, but I personally wouldn't do it unless you're aiming for humour. It would be very hard to do without coming off as at least a little flippant.

Comment: I agree that it comes across as only appropriate for humor.  I could imagine an author like Terry Pratchett doing it, but it wouldn't work in a more serious work of fantasy.

Answer (score 0):

Not really - you would be inventing new words if you did that. Some people might find it sexist to use "man" rather than something more gender-neutral like "person", but "personpower", "swordperson", etc. are not standard English. If you replaced "man" with something else the meaning would probably be understood, but again, it would sound like a made-up word.

EDIT to add: I think it might work better if you hyphenated the words, e.g. "police-elf" or "dwarf-power" - this might be more "acceptable" English.

And to answer your other question, the singular of "elves" is "elf". The plural of "dwarf" is either "dwarfs" or "dwarves".